# Nativescript autocomplete in ios crash

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hi all am trying to achieve an autocomplete using nativescript for a project. It was working fine with nativescript-pro-ui, but i updated that plugin to nativescript-ui-autocomplete. Afterwards it begins to crash whenever i try to invoke that in ios, it works fine in android.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you try adding and removing platform?

Comment: and also did you import nativescript-ui-autocomplete in module?

Comment: yeah, tried all those, but it keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two open issues about a crash in iOS. I see this is an old issue and they are probably not related to this one but I'm listing them here for reference.

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9031

https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1487